# Read PCI config address for PCI device iteration

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, pci

I want to find all PCI devices with as little Linux use as possible because of exercise.

I find in scattered docs to read address 0xCF8 or maybe there is some protocol where I write to that address in RAM but I haven't been able to hack it.

Any attempts to read that address or write some config address to write to it segfault in simple C/C++ programs. I thought I might need ring 0 so I created a Linux kernel module but the program got killed just trying to read that 0xCF8 address as a MULL pointer dereference?

I am aware of `lspci`, /sys/bus, etc... This is a little more advanced please.

Comment: 0xCF8 is not a memory mapped address, it's an IO port, and if you don't want to rely on linux functions to access it, you will need to use assembly, in particular the instructions `out` and `in`

Comment: Modern systems have PCI config space mapped to memory (MMIO) addresses; that makes it a lot easier and quicker to access. The ACPI table "MCFG" has the MMIO address.

Comment: To use CF8/CFC, you have to write the address of the PCI register that you want to access to I/O port CF8h using `out` and then access the register by reading or writing to CFCh using `in` or `out`. See https://wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_configuration_space.

Comment: I have the IO port working now. Didn't get IO port vs. mem map init. I'll get the mem map. Is there a reason for pref? Docs are '05 like Wales

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do everything you want in userspace using [pcilib](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pcilib.7.html), which is used by `lspci`, etc., but isn't well documented. If you must use kernel code, carry on reading…

Linux kernel code can use the `for_each_pci_dev()` macro and pointers to `struct pci_dev` (both defined by `#include <linux/pci.h>`) to iterate over all PCI device like this:

```c
struct pci_dev *pdev;

pdev = NULL; /* IMPORTANT: Start with NULL unless continuing a previous loop. */
for_each_pci_dev(pdev) {
    /* Examine pdev-> members here. */
}
```

Each iteration of the loop will decrement ("put") the reference count of the current `struct pci_dev` pointed to by `pdev` (if it is not `NULL`) and will increment ("get") the reference count of the next `struct pci_dev` pointed to by `pdev`. When the loop terminates naturally after the last PCI device has been seen, `pdev` will be `NULL`. If the code breaks out of the loop early so that `pdev` is still valid, it may need to decrement ("put") the reference with `pci_dev_put(pdev);` when it has finished with it.

`for_each_pci_dev(pdev)` uses `pci_get_device()` internally, so you could replace `for_each_pci_dev(pdev)` with the following `while` loop:

```c
struct pci_dev *pdev;

pdev = NULL; /* IMPORTANT: Start with NULL unless continuing a previous loop. */
while ((pdev = pci_get_device(PCI_ANY_ID, PCI_ANY_ID, pdev) != NULL) {
    /* Examine pdev-> members here. */
}
```

The `PCI_ANY_ID` value matches any PCI vendor ID or PCI device ID, so you can change the first two arguments of `pci_get_device()` to only iterate over PCI devices with a specific vendor and/or device ID.

Using your own `while` (or `for`) loop also allows you to change the `pci_get_device()` calls to similar functions. For example `pci_get_subsys()` can match devices with specific PCI vendor, device, subsystem vendor, and/or subsystem device IDs, and `pci_get_class()` can match devices with specific PCI class codes.

Comment: I think I got it. I didn't get it

Comment: You need to take `pci_rescan_remove_lock`. PCI is hotpluggable bus. Also even after getting a pointer to a PCI device object it may be already stale.

Comment: @0andriy It should work fine without using the rescan remove lock, although the list of PCI devices may be slightly fuzzy if devices are added or removed during the traversal through the list. The pointers to the `struct pci_dev` objects will not go stale, although it is possible that the underlying hardware may have been surprise removed.